# ng-model not getting updated on command paste in safari browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this search textbox which searches the text. If i am adding text character by character its working fine but when i am pasting data directly into textbox my ng-model is not getting updated. This issue is only with **safari** **browser**.

This is my html

```
<div class="div-input pull-left" ng-submit="submitFilterForm()" ng-class="{ 'filter-dropdown-adjustment' : showFilterState() }">
            <input type="text" class="filter-input" ng-model="query" my-
     enter="submitFilterForm()" auto-focus />
        </div>
```

my-enter is my custom directive for click on press of enter key

My directive

```
    'use strict';

  define([
'angular',
'./module',
      ], function(angular, directives) {

/**
 * Like ngShow but uses CSS visibility instead of display
 */
directives.directive('myEnter', [
    function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
                if (event.which === 13) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.$eval(attrs.geEnter);
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        };
    }
])
```

});

This is my js file which contains $watch function on ng-model for textbox

```
       $scope.$watch("query", function(name) {
            $scope.validationError = false;
            console.log("value of query is", name);
            filterStateService.updateSearchQuery(name);
        });
```

Comment: Because a paste isn't a `keydown` or a `keypress`, try and use `element.bind("input")`

Comment: Hi @ashworx, please consider using 'change' in element.bind as follows `element.bind("change keydown keypress", function(event) {` . I hope it will work.

Comment: it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. I have used `ng-paste`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.handlePaste =function(e){
      setTimeout(function(){
      $scope.query = e.target.value;
      console.log(e.target.value,"val")
     },10)
      
    }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <input type="text" ng-paste="handlePaste($event)" ng-model="query" />
{{query}}

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey i tried your solution its working fine in IE and chrome but in safari value of query field is undefined.

Comment: What you getting in console.?

Comment: $scope.handlePaste = function (val) {
             console.log("M in handlepaste",val);
               $scope.query = val;
             };  value is coming as undefined

Comment: value is coming as undefined in safari browser

Comment: @ashworx why are you not using the updated anser apprach. `$scope.handlePaste =function(e){
      $scope.query = e.target.value;
     console.log(e.target.value,"val")
    }`

Comment: @ashworx I have added a hack. This should work for you. Refer the updated answer

Comment: Hey i tried your updated solution also same thing happening again when i manually enter character by character it is taking but when i am doing command paste at that time value is not getting updated in my model. n m getting empty value

Comment: My question is do you see value in console in Safari browser?

Comment: No its not coming

Comment: I also tested the code which you gave in safari it was working fine but when i am using this code in my project at that time i am not getting any value.

Comment: So issue is now with something else. Update your questions.